# HTML frame's onload is called before the content is loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, greasemonkey, dom-events, html-frames

I am writing a simple Greasemonkey script for Java SE API reference doc [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ ]. It goes as:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id          Test
// @grant       none
// @include     http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/*
// @version     1
// @run-at      docuitment-end
// ==UserScript==


var classNamesFrame = null;
var classNamesDoc = null;
var classNamesATags = null;
var classNames = null;

function printClassNames()
{
  classNamesATags = classNamesDoc.getElementsByTagName('a');
  classNames = new Array();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < classNamesATags.length; i++) {
    classNames.push(classNamesATags[i].textContent);
  }
  console.log(classNames);
  console.log(classNamesDoc.URL);
  console.log('Total number of classes: ' + classNamesATags.length);
  alert("printClassNames called");
}


classNamesFrame = document.getElementsByName('packageFrame') [0];
classNamesDoc = classNamesFrame.contentDocument;
classNamesFrame.onload = printClassNames;
//classNamesFrame.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", printClassNames, false);
```

Function `printClassNames()` prints names of all classes it finds in the frame where all classes are listed. I should do so when the frame has finished loading. But the `onload` even is called before HTML document for the frame is loaded.

I have tried using `DOMContentLoaded` event but it is not even called.

What can I do so that `printClassNames` is called after the frame has finished loading completely?

Comment: How are the contents of the frame populated? Server-side or via AJAX?

Comment: @ChrisHardie Its via server (if I understand you correctly), as:

`<frame src="allclasses-frame.html" name="packageFrame" title="All classes and interfaces (except non-static nested types)">`

Comment: How are all the classes loaded into the frame?

Comment: @ChrisHardie Frame has an associated HTML source and the browser loads them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script has a variety of errors (list below), but the main one is that it's grabbing the wrong `contentDocument`.

This is because Firefox returns `<about:blank>` for frame contents until it is replaced by the actual page contents. The `classNamesDoc` variable remains pointed at the blank value. (Note that Chrome handles frames slightly differently and updates `classNamesDoc` for you.)

So, move `classNamesDoc = classNamesFrame.contentDocument;` to inside `printClassNames()` and the most obvious problem is solved.

Other problems, "worstest firstest":

- **Badly malformed metadata block.** Incorrect `// ==/UserScript==` line.  This causes the script to run (and crash) for every page and (i)frame you browse!
- **Script silently crashes** (on Firefox, Chrome reports these errors) for every page/frame but one small subset. You need to check the value of `classNamesFrame` before using it.

  For example, on the `docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/` pages, this script is running 4 times and silently crashing on three of those.
- **Missing `@name` directive.**  This can cause scoping, updating, and maintenance problems -- as well as hamper uploading and sharing the script.
- **Syntax error.** It should be: `@run-at document-end`, except that you probably do not need this directive at all, in this case.

Putting it all together, your script would be:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @grant       none
// @include     http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

var classNamesFrame = null;
var classNamesDoc = null;
var classNamesATags = null;
var classNames = null;

function printClassNames()
{
  classNamesDoc = classNamesFrame.contentDocument;
  classNamesATags = classNamesDoc.getElementsByTagName('a');
  classNames = new Array();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < classNamesATags.length; i++) {
    classNames.push(classNamesATags[i].textContent);
  }
  console.log(classNames);
  console.log(classNamesDoc.URL);
  console.log('Total number of classes: ' + classNamesATags.length);
  console.log("printClassNames called");
}

classNamesFrame = document.getElementsByName('packageFrame') [0];
if (classNamesFrame) {
    classNamesFrame.onload = printClassNames;
}
```

-- which works on Both Firefox and Chrome (and probably others).

Comment: Thanks :) Is there a document about behavior of browsers over how and when they render or populate DOM?

Comment: Not at this level that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @version     1
// @include     http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var classNamesATags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var classNames = [].map.call(classNamesATags, function(e) {
    return e.textContent;
});
console.log(classNames);
console.log(document.URL);
console.log('Total number of classes: ' + classNamesATags.length);
alert('printClassNames called');
```